# Copy Protected excel workbook into another workbook python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to open a protected Excel file and copy the contents to another file I'm using this following snippet:

```
import win32com.client

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
filename='C:/Users/sh/Documents/Supply.xls'
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename,False,True,None)

for sheet in xlwb.Worksheets:
    xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    nwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    sheet.Copy(Before=nwb.Workheets('Sheet1'))
    nwb.SaveAs("C:/Users/sh/Documents/"+sheet.Name+'.xlsx') # Line 9
    nwb.Close(True)
```

However, I'm not able to copy the contents as it throws an exception at 
line number 9 saying 'Microsoft Excel Cannot Access the file at (line 9)

Is there any other method to copy contents of protected Excel workbook to another workbook in python?

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
filename='C:/Py/Input/Supply.xls'
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename,False,True,None)
sheet= xlwb.Sheets(1)
shhet1=xlwb.Sheets(2)
nwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
sheet.Copy(Before=nwb.Sheets(1))
nwb.SaveAs('Sheet1.csv',24)
nwb.Close(True)
nwb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
shhet1.Copy(Before=nwb1.Sheets(1))
nwb1.SaveAs('Sheet2.csv',24)
nwb1.Close(True)
```